# Not using CSS classes on each TD to style; using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I normally tag the first TD in a form row with a "header" class and the adjacent TD with the "data" class.

Instead of writing all this in the HTML I use the following jQuery:

```
$("tr").find("td:eq(0)").addClass("header");
$("tr").find("td:eq(1)").addClass("data");
```

Is this efficient?

Comment: why don't you use `th` for a table header?

Comment: Well he says that the header is a cell, that shares a row with data. I'm having trouble imagining what this table actually looks like, though.

Comment: Sorry the header is a label/caption (I'm not using CSS to structure my forms because I can't get them to look right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be quicker and more efficient to use css. The following css would have the same effect.

```
td:first-child {background-color:blue;}
td:first-child + td {background-color:yellow;}
```

Also depends on how large your table is obviously.

Comment: No, you are not right. There is full support for sibling selectors (td + td) in IE7 and IE8. Full support for first-child pseudo selector in IE8, partial in IE7. Make sure you do not have comments before your td, here are references that may help you. http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=3FAF0 and http://f6design.com/journal/2008/11/27/ie7-first-child-and-html-comments/

Answer (score 1):

Efficient?  Yes
Easy to read and support?  Not so much

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously more efficient in terms of space on the large scale. Less efficient for people viewing/executing your document if a lot of javascript has to be run before viewing.

Answer (score 0):

Efficient enough.

Some ways to optimize:

1. `$("#someid tr").find... // the ID will narrow the scope of the search`
2. Can you apply the data class as simply the default TR styling and then spec the unique TR as header class?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define efficiency.  Is it less code for you to write?  Sure.

Will it be faster or slower to execute in the browser than regular CSS?  Typically slower.  How much so depends on the client browser as well as the structure and size of the table.

A large table will obviously take longer for the javascript to execute on.  Large in this case *might* be hundreds (or thousands) of rows depending on the browser.  Longer might mean 500ms or so.  Newer browsers have faster javascript runtimes so it might not even be noticeable.

However, if your table is structured correctly (e.g. you are using table-layout:fixed) and have exactly defined widths (e.g. you are not using percentages or anything else that requires a calculation) then the fastest possible method of rendering would be to just set the class attribute in the html.